# Unity Animator How to Remove Transition

Tags: unity-game-engine, animation

I am trying to create an animation with sprites, and I am having an issue with the transitions. When I set frame 0's y-position to 0 and frame 30's y-position to 5, frame 15's y-position will be 2.5.

I am trying to remove this transition for one animation so that the y-position instantly snaps to 5 at frame 30 while frame 29's y-position is still 0. I tried setting frame 29's y-position to 0 manually, but when the framerate gets high enough the transition is noticeable, which is making my animation look messy.

Is there a way to remove this transition entirely from one or more specific animations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can remove the transition by editing the animation curve tangents.

At the bottom of the Animation window, go to Curves.
Right click the points you want to edit the transition for.
Change the appropriate tangents to Constant.

This should eliminate any transition.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! BTW how do you add images to your answers? I have run into several questions that I could've answered with an image.

Comment: For this one I just copied and pasted a screenshot into my answer and it figured it out for me.